# using masking to change string in an array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array that looks like this:

```
a = [['3','4','5','gg','5','6','7'],
     ['3','ww','6','7','4','2','3']]
```

Is there a smart way to convert only the non digit elements to be 0?

Comment: Is this actually a NumPy array?  Or is it a nested Python list?

Comment: It is a numpy array

Comment: What is the `dtype`?  `shape`?

Comment: dtype = str , shape (7,7)

Comment: are digits more than 9?

Comment: yes they can be

Comment: That's a Python list literal, so it's not a numpy array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is nested Python `list`

```
[list(map(lambda x:0 if type(x)== str else x,a1)) for a1 in a]
Out[35]: [[3, 4, 5, 0, 5, 6, 7], [3, 0, 6, 7, 4, 2, 3]]
```

If it is `np.array`
Since you change your question

```
s = lambda x: x.isalpha()
func = np.vectorize(s)
a[func(a)]='0'
a=a.astype(int)
a
Out[55]: 
array([[3, 4, 5, 0, 5, 6, 7],
       [3, 0, 6, 7, 4, 2, 3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` has a method `np.core.defchararray.isdigit` for checking whether strings are formed only from digits.

```
b = np.array([['3','4','5','gg','5','6','7'],
              ['3','ww','6','7','4','2','3']])

np.core.defchararray.isdigit(b)

Out: array([[ True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True],
            [ True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Using this with `np.where`, one will gets the desired output.

```
np.where(np.core.defchararray.isdigit(b), b, "0")

Out: array([['3', '4', '5', '0', '5', '6', '7'],
            ['3', '0', '6', '7', '4', '2', '3']], dtype='<U2')
```

Reference

[numpy.core.defchararray.isdigit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.isdigit.html#numpy.core.defchararray.isdigit)